# Css left transition dont work with height and left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make somekind of `toolbox`, I need make toolbox apearing from left on opening, so I make transition from `left=-1500px to left=0;` and that works fine.

when I try make some kind of minimalization adding transition to `height=0;width=0;` after I added: `transition: width, height 1s linear;` transition left stop working.

Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/wsghc65c/7/

my css:

```
.modal {
    visibility: visible;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    transition: visibility 0.1s linear;
    transition: left 1s linear;
    transition: width, height 1s linear;
}

.modal-content {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 80vh;
    mac-width: 86vh;
}

.modal-left-hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    left: -1500px;
}

.modal.minimized {
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
    left: 10vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting the transition. You can't define a value 3 times in css. It will take the last one `width, height 1s linear` as his value because it's defined last.

Comment: when I 've changed to `transition: left, width, height 1s linear;` still don't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/wsghc65c/16/

Add the height width transition to the minimized class. You might want to set overflow hidden too.

```
.modal.minimized {
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
    left: 10vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    transition: width 1s linear, height 1s linear;
}
```